# При запуске .py скрипта из ярлыка в линуксе меняется рабочая директория

Tags: python, linux

На рабочем столе есть ярлык на `script.py`
Так вот, если запускать сам `script.py`, то рабочая директория будет такой, какой и должна быть (/home/my-projects/tested).
Но, если запускать `.desktop` который ссылается на `script.py`, то рабочей папкой будет уже (/home/qwerty).

Так вот, как заставить ярлык выполнять `script.py` именно в его изначальной директории, а не в той, в которой лежит ярлык?

Comment: Ну, просто пропишите нужный вам chdir внутри скрипта, например?

Comment: а вроде и внутри desktop файла можно рабочий каталог прописать.

Comment: а причем здесь python?

Comment: @KoVadim [можно](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#key-path) (но нужно ли?)

Comment: так скрипт может находится в любой папке, и поэтому каждый раз писать chdir такое себе решение

Comment: просто автор вопроса не знал, что это от питона не зависит. Вполне нормально поставленный вопрос.

Comment: @strawdog, сам скрипт на питоне прост

Comment: @524532453254523523455234 ну так просто получите путь к папке, в которой находится скрипт, и просто сделайте в него chdir, не?

Comment: @andreymal а как это сделать если при запуске скрипта через ярлык рабочая папка левая?

Comment: Вообще пофиг на левую рабочую папку: `os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))`

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо, то что нужно)